# Flutter | How to store List of List<String> in Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use flutter's shared preferences plugin to save a lists of strings inside a list.

```
[
  ["str1", "str2"],
  ["str3", "str4"]
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please describe your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
const temp = json.encode({'data':[
  ["str1", "str2"],
  ["str3", "str4"]
]});
```

then save `temp` in your sharedpref. Do not to forget to use `json.decode` after getting this string from your sharedPref.